# Given two data sets with 3 columns, extract the rows for which the value of the third column is almost equal in both data sets

Tags: python, numpy, math, floating-point

Given these two data sets:

`data_set_1.txt`: https://pastebin.com/VQrsv8kU

`data_set_2.txt`: https://pastebin.com/jFBa6kZq

(It is possible to download these without registering)

I am trying to obtain the values of `x_1`, `y_1`, `x_2` and `y_2` for which:

`z_1 = z_2` (within a threshold).

Is there a way to do this?

1) Both data sets do not have the same length,

2) Since `z_1` and `z_2` will never be exactly equal, I have tried the following:

```
import numpy as np
y_1, z_1, x_1 = np.loadtxt('./data_set_1.txt').T    
y_2, z_2, x_2 = np.loadtxt('./data_set_2.txt').T

threshold = 0.000005
for i in z_1:
 for j in z_2:
   if abs(i - j) < threshold:
   print "i = ", ('%.13f' % i)
   print "j = ", ('%.13f' % j)
```

The result is the following:

```
i =  -941.4594925722633
j =  -941.4594947788443
i =  -941.4456535625201
j =  -941.4456565008313
i =  -941.4291125503427
j =  -941.4291149979141
i =  -941.4326065311985
j =  -941.4326072530644
i =  -941.4098552554067
j =  -941.4098593315858
i =  -941.4138389914422
j =  -941.4138343941854
i =  -941.3961673813864
j =  -941.3961719676133
i =  -941.3984112845883
j =  -941.3984098947884
i =  -941.3838698217477
j =  -941.3838733787329
i =  -941.4001013025463
j =  -941.4001055479807
```

It is possible to check that this is working because `i =  -941.4594925722633` is found on the `z_1` column of `./data_set_1.dat`, and  `j =  -941.4594947788443` is found on `./data_set_2.dat`.

Now, each of these printed `i` results contain a `x_1` and `y_1`

Similarly, each of these `j` results contain a `x_2` and `y_2`

I cannot manage to extract `x_1`, `y_1`, `x_2` and `y_2`

Comment: You do not show us any of your own attempts. Have you tried anything yourself, and what were the problems with that approach? Also, do you want an approach that scales well for larger datasets?

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yes, sorry, I had some attempts, (I just wanted to keep the question short) - edited

Comment: @Rory Daulton Done

Comment: Since they have different lengths, are you trying to find the rows for which  z1 is within a threshold of any z2?

Comment: @user2699 Yes, that's right

Comment: As for your  last question, `-941.459494779` is just the rounded value of `-941.4594947788443` displayed by python.

Comment: @user2699 Correct, by printing the result with more decimals figures, see please updated post

Comment: I'd suggest putting the data into an SQL database and doing a JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Here is an outline of an approach that would work.

Sort each dataset in increasing order by the values of `z`: i.e. `z_1` and `z_2`. Then set an index for each dataset. Scan through them, advancing an index when the item in that dataset is too low to be compared with the item pointed to in the other dataset. When the compared items are close enough, act on the pair of items. You are done when both indices reach the end of their datasets. This is similar to how mergesort is done. The different sizes of the datasets will not affect the algorithm.

This algorithm does not look particularly Pythonic and it does not use the strengths of numpy but it has the advantage that it works. This second stage has a time complexity `O(n)` so it is fast. The sorting stage has time complexity `O(n log(n))` so it is the slow part.

---

Regarding your added code attempt: `i` and `j` are poor variable names for values of `z_1` and `z_2`. If `ndx1` and `ndx2` are the indices into your two datasets and the "threshold" for equality is `threshold`, you can test for near-equality with:

```
if abs(z_1[ndx1] - z_2[ndx2]) < threshold:
   do_whatever
```

The value of `threshold` would be something like `1e-5`.

But here is code more closely related to what you want. This assumes that the datasets are already set up and sorted by their `z` values.

```
threshold = 1e-5

length1, length2 = len(z_1), len(z_2)
if length1 == 0 or length2 == 0:
    return
ndx1 = ndx2 = 0
z1, z2 = z_1[0], z_2[0]

while True:
    if z1 + threshold <= z2:  # z_1 too low
        ndx1 += 1
        if ndx1 == length1:
            return
        z1 = z_1[ndx1]
    elif z2 + threshold <= z1:  # z_2 too low
        ndx2 += 1
        if ndx2 == length2:
            return
        z2 = z_2[ndx2]
    else:  # z_1 and z_2 almost equal
        do_whatever
        # adjust ndx1, ndx2
```

This is just a skeleton. How you adjust `ndx1` and `ndx2` at the end depends on whether or not you want to allow one value of `z_1` being almost-equal to more than value of `z_2` or the reverse.

Comment: If you run `if abs(z_1[ndx1] - z_2[ndx2]) < threshold:` over a simple 2 lists example, it returns: `IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices` - Please see edited post

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough start using only numpy:

```
idx = abs(z1 - z2[:, None]) < threshold
idx1 = idx.any(0)
idx2 = idx.any(1)
```

`idx1` and `idx2` can then be used to get the associated rows, eg with `y1[idx1]`, `y2[idx2]`, etc.

The code works by making a pairwise comparison of all elements in `z1`, `z2`, then finding any element where one of those comparisons is less than the threshold.
For a large dataset, the answer by Rory will be faster and use much less memory since it only calculates the comparison where needed.  For the smaller datasets, like the one given, the speedup from eliminating loops should be substantial.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however with this code you end up with booleans instead of the actual values - please see updated post

Comment: @DavidC Numpy allows using boolean arrays to index a similar sized array.   I've edited to include an example of this.